# Strange behavior of ORM in Django for ManyToMany field

Tags: django, orm

I try to choose all `Offers` available in `City` with `id=1`, but instead I get result multiple by X times, where X is number of `Shops` with `city_id=1`:

models.py:

```
class Cities(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Shop(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.ManyToManyField(to=Cities)

class Product(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Offer(models.Model):    
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product)
    shop = models.ManyToManyField(to=Shop)
```

views.py:

```
print Offer.objects.all().filter(shop__city=1)
```

I want:
`[<Offer: Test1>]`

But I get:
`[<Offer: Test1>, <Offer: Test1>, <Offer: Test1>]`

I had 1 `Offer` record and 3 `Shop` records (with same city) in my database.
Could you show me what I understand wrong about ManyToMany relations/request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as Blog.objects.all() don't introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it's possible to get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That's when you'd use distinct().

You need to apply the `distinct()` method, So you may need to do :

```
print Offer.objects.all().filter(shop__city=1).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are placing a join on 3 table. Its going to return you the result with the offers for all the shops in that city. Try to do this

```
Offer.objects.all().filter(shop__city=1).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Offer.objects.filter(shop__city__id = 1).distinct()
```